# Existing library for quick menu like in Google+ app?

Tags: android

A design pattern I've noticed being used recently in some Android apps is a simple textual list menu similar to QuickActions in that it pops up in a speech-bubble-like View when summoned. The Google+ app uses it for overflow items, for example.

[image]

Does anybody know of a library that'll let me easily implement these kinds of menus in my own app or, if not, what the most straightforward way of doing it from scratch would be?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a standard widget, but you can use: [QuickAction](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/) dialog. Or you wan't something else?

Comment: The "Gallery3D-like QuickActions" example on that page is what I'm looking for. I'll take a look at the source code and give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: May I ask you, if you are observing too, that if you tap on some item on QuickAction, it disapears for a short moment before the whole popup is gone? I'd like to know if it's just a problem in my emulator. thank you

Comment: I've just gotten around to implementing it, and I do indeed encounter that problem on my physical device. Not a deal breaker, but I'll let you know if I come across the cause. Thanks again!